# use an array of unknown length in where clause of mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am writing an SQL query. I have an array of unknown length and I want to select the data fromMySQL by using that array in the WHERE clause of the query. This is my query right now and it is working fine

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT messagesutou.SenderID from messagesutou where (messagesutou.SenderID !='$items[1]' AND messagesutou.SenderID !='$items[0]' AND messagesutou.SenderID !='$items[2]') AND messagesutou.RecieverID='$uid'";
```

But in this I know the length of array ( 3) and I just used the array name with index for testing purpose. Now i want to know if array length is unknown then how would I write this query?

Comment: Where the array comes from? I think you look for `where messagesutou.SenderID not in (...)`

Comment: it comes from retorfit android library

Comment: i think u have understood what i want in my query

Comment: WARNING: Your code is at risk from SQL Injection attacks and needs to be re-written using PHP Prepared Statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$list = implode(',', $items);
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT SenderID 
FROM messagesutou 
WHERE 0 = FIND_IN_SET(SenderID, '$list')
  AND RecieverID='$uid'
```

or (taken from [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3636601/jens)'s answer which was deleted by him)

```
SELECT DISTINCT SenderID 
FROM messagesutou 
WHERE SenderID NOT IN ($list)
  AND RecieverID='$uid'
```

The difference - both variants are applicable when `SenderID` and `$items` values have a numeric type, only the former when they have string type, none when they have string type and contain commas or ticks.

But the latter may be adapted:

```
$list = '\''.implode('\',\'', $items).'\'';
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT SenderID 
FROM messagesutou 
WHERE SenderID NOT IN ($list)
  AND RecieverID='$uid'
```

It now acccepts any datatype and allows commas (but not ticks - they must be quoted before imploding).

Comment: You should be using PDO or MySQLi prepared statements

Comment: i m using mysqli

Comment: @Martin i use OP's method.

Comment: @Akina better to show the OP the problems with their current method. It's fundamentally insecure.

Comment: i got an error actually when i write only $items it gives output Array but when i write $item[n] it gives corresponding value at n index